# Trying to setup App Locker and it is blocking Domain Admins even though I have Domain admins to allow access to everything

Tags: applocker

Trying to setup App Locker and it is blocking Domain Admins even though I have Domain admins to allow access to everything.

I have it set up to allow domain admins and local admins to access everything
And I have it setup to limit Everyone and Domain Users.

I have it running in audit mode.

However, when I try to run a .exe, .msi, script, app Event log still shows that if the app locker policy was being enforced the actions of the domain admin would be blocked.

I tried running the items (a .exe installer, a .msi installer, a script, and notepad) by running it normally and by right clicking and selecting run as administrator (on the items that I could, the msi didn't have that option to run as admin).

Either way I still see in event log that the action would be blocked.

- For the exe option I did "domain\domain admins", set path to * and
  set to allow
- For the MSI I option I did "domain\domain admins", set path to * and
  set to allow
- For the Script Option I did "domain\domain admins", set path to * and
  set to allow
- For the App Option I did "domain\domain admins", set package and
  publisher to *, version set to 0.0.0.0 and above and set to allow

I have Local Admins with same settings

- Domain Users with deny all except for windows files
- Everyone with deny all except for windows files

Am I missing something? Why is it still blocking domain admins? I need domain admins to still be able to access and execute things to provide support.

Comment: If you get rid of the Everyone rule does the allow rules work? Care to provide a screenshot it's been awhile since I attempted to create an AppLocker policy GPO..

Comment: Doesn't make a difference to remove everyone. Not sure what exactly you want a screenshot of, there are a number of screenshots that would have to be uploaded.